# Can’t move slider in audio player

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a slider that I placed in the xcode story board but I can’t move it. When I try to move the slider on my phone, it doesn’t move. I’m I supposed to add an action selector to it?

Comment: Adding an action is not required to be able to drag a slider's thumb. You need to make sure that the slider actually responds to touches. For instance, it might be added as a subview of another view for which `isUserInteractionEnabled` is set to `false`, or it can be obscured by another view which actually intercepts touch events.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the timer with that slider

```
var timer : Timer? = nil {
        willSet {
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
    }

 func startTimer() {
        stopTimer()
        guard timer == nil else { return }
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.7, target: self, selector: #selector(updateSlider), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    func stopTimer() {
        guard timer != nil else { return }
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
       @objc func updateSlider(){
        if let currentItem = audioPlayer.currentItem {
            let duration = currentItem.duration
            if (CMTIME_IS_INVALID(duration)) {
                // Do sth
                return;
            }
            let currentTime = currentItem.currentTime()
            seekBar.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(currentTime) / CMTimeGetSeconds(duration))
        }
    }
```